# UINavigation Bar and UITabBar programmatically - All objects are disabled?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Ok this is bizarre and has been bugging me for days now.... I did it correctly (I think) but it

This was all done in the AppDelegate:

```
//Initialize the controllers

 navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
 iVacationTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];


//Define the viewcontrollers

 myTools* vc_tools = [[myTools alloc] init];
 mySettings* vc_settings = [[mySettings alloc] init];
 aboutIVacation* vc_about = [[aboutIVacation alloc] init];
 myCurrent *mycurrentpage = [[myCurrent alloc] init];
//Create the array of controllers

 NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mycurrentpage,  vc_tools,vc_settings, vc_about, nil];

//Add the view controllers to the tab bars:

 [iVacationTabBar setViewControllers: controllers animated:YES];

//Push the first view controller to the stack:

 [navController pushViewController: mycurrentpage animated:NO];

//Add the tabBar and navController to the window:

 [window addSubview:iVacationTabBar.view];
 [window addSubview:navController.view];
```

What am I doing wrong. I cant get any of the elements on the page to work. I have a button on mycurrentpage that is also not working.

Comment: did you check "user interaction enabled"?

Comment: These are programmatically done... is there a way to do it in code?

Comment: Update: I also added these iines hoping to fix it but still no help:mycurrentpage.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 iVacationTabBar.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 navController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!!! Solved the problem from help from another forum post:

I had the lines reversed
I had to add the nav controller's sub view before the tab bar